# When creating a variable from this parameter, the result is always nil, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm submitting a form to create a new record of my SpecialDeal model.  The params submitted look like this:

```
@_params    
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cl1SwnHOum8d/kiGnwkDsamG5IMbmdnoeFvlY11KpKc=", "special_deal"=>{"title"=>"5", "provider"=>"5", "description"=>"5", "deal_price"=>"", "conditions"=>"", "expires"=>"07/18/2013 14:38:18", "excerpt"=>"", "original_price"=>"", "phone_number"=>"", "street"=>"", "city"=>"", "postal_code"=>"", "state"=>"", "country"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Special deal", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"special_deals"}
```

Yet when I try to make a variable out of the `expires` param...

```
def create
  expiration = params[:expires]
```

That variable always sets itself as nil!

```
Local Variables

expiration: nil
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try with params["special_deal"]["expires"]

Answer (score 3):

expires is in inner hash which is under 'special_deal' key so try

```
def create
  expiration = params[:special_deal][:expires]
```

i'm assuming you are using rails params

Answer (score 2):

As I commented earlier it. Now adding it as my answer ;)

```
def create
  expiration = params["special_deal"]["expires"]
  # Your code goes here
end
```